# Relation between $\delta$-system

Tags: tensor-calculus, linear-algebra, linear-systems, matrix-elements

I'm reading Pavel Grinfeld's book "Introduction to tensor analysis and the calculus of moving surfaces". I've reached the section where the author talks about $\delta$-systems and the relations that bind one to the others (section 9.4, page 138). In particular there is an exercise I couldn't get done: it asks to justify the relation:

$$ 3 \delta^i_j = \delta^{ij}_{rj} $$

(in the l.h.s. there is a $j$ at the place I assume belongs to an $r$, but it could be a simple index renaming). This expression is evaluated in four dimensions. Now after this equation the author explains that:

$$ \delta^{ij}_{rs} = \det\begin{bmatrix}
\delta^i_r & \delta^i_s \\ 
\delta^j_r & \delta^j_s \\ 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Hence I assume that the contraction reduces to the above equation to:

$$ \delta^{ij}_{rs} = \det\begin{bmatrix}
\delta^i_r & \delta^i_j \\ 
\delta^j_r & \delta^j_j \\ 
\end{bmatrix} = \delta^i_r - \delta^i_j \delta^j_r = \delta^i_r - \delta^i_r = 0$$

But this contradicts the fact that $ 3 \delta^i_j = \delta^{ij}_{rj} $. What am I doing wrong? How could I solve this exercise?

P.S. Thank you for your answers in advance and excuse my poor English, I'm still practising it.

Comment: $\delta_j^j$ is the upper limit of the sum on $j$ (dimension of the manifold on which you have the tensor fields). And in this case I guess it's 4. That gives you the desired result

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My error was to equal $\delta^j_j$ to 1 and not to $4$. Thank again!